# Accessing via www. will show Nginx welcome page [+ Gunicorn + Django]

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, nginx-config

Nginx + Ubuntu 18.04 + Django 2.2.10

Accessing directly via "www.examples.com" will show nginx welcome page, but accessing anything else--"examples.com", "https://examples.com", "https://www.examples.com"--will work as expected.

On DigitalOcean, I have two A-type records [www.examples.com, examples.com] directing to the IP address--I believe they are correctly set up.
On my Django project, I have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'examples.com', '137.68.49.136', 'www.examples.com']` set.

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/project:

```
server {
    server_name examples.com www.examples.com;
    charset     UTF-8;

    error_log   /home/jay/eco/nginx-error.log;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static {
        alias /home/jay/eco/static;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/jay/eco/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/examples.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/examples.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certb$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = examples.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name examples.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I believed this was everything but apparently not. What am I missing?

Comment: You do not have a `server` block defined for `http://www.example.com` so Nginx is using the default server block (presumably) defined elsewhere. Try adding `www.example.com` to the `server_name` directive in the second `server` block (and you will need to fix the logic in that block too).

Comment: @RichardSmith I've tried adding `www.example.com` into the `server_name` directive and it gives me a 404. Is this progress? Could you point me in the right direction to fix the logic? I'm not sure what's wrong there.

Comment: Yes, progress. I would remove the `if` block entirely and replace the `return 404;` with `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`

Comment: you, sir, are a wizard. not sure if you care to post it as an answer? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `server` blocks, the first processes requests using the `https` protocol and the second processes requests using the `http` protocol. There is also a default `server` block in some other file, which responds with the Nginx welcome page.

The second `server` block in your question only processes requests for `http://example.com`. You need to add `www.example.com` to the `server_name` directive, and update the logic so that both domain names are redirected to the `https` service.

For example:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.